# FTP User Isolation

Tags: windows, http, iis, iis-7, ftp

I have a website set up as an FTP server too.

I want to use the FTP server to allow to access content from a folder outside the root.

I guess this could set up easily by adding a virtual directory. Problem is that I dont want the users to see this outside folder by browsing to the site by http.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but only by adding a standalone FTP site instead of adding FTP access to an existing site.

To add a separate FTP site, right click on the "Sites" node in the left hand "Connections" pane in IIS Manager.

You do have to make sure that you enable "Virtual Directories" in the FTP Directory Browsing options.